# How should I explain to the senior members of my team that our CTO is also our stakeholder?

Tags: management, customer-service

The context is the following.

During a corporate restructuring that happens this year, there were many resignations and layoff in my current company. Our CTO lives in New Zealand and we are based in Belgium.

The team I'm currently managing is brand new. However, among the remaining guys, the feeling is that the CTO did not help find solutions during this transition time. Many of the guys were left on their own, this leading to resignations.

True or not, I'm not sure. But I can say that from far, the CTO , my direct line manager cares about the wellbeing of the team and the successful outcome of the projects.

Since I'm here, he is taking extra care to reinforce his distant authority by having a bi-weekly call with me and is very curious about what is going on with the team:

Is the project on schedule, is the customer happy, etc?

The feeling among senior members is that we only own the customer, results, not our CTO, and that he is going default us at some points, so why do we need to please him.

My question is the following:

- Should I mentioned to my team that past is past, and that we need to move forward, regardless of what has happened in the past and also use some pedagogy to explain that our CTO is a de-facto stakeholder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I mentioned to my team that past is past, and that we need to
>   move forward, regardless of what has happened in the past and also use
>   some pedagogy to explain that our CTO is a de-facto stakeholder?

Without knowing what is meant by "we need to please him", your team will have nothing actionable to do. Instead of talking to your team in such sweeping generalities, tell them specifically what they have to do, and which approvals are required.

For example:

- If they need to build a feature because the CTO wants it, just direct them to build the feature.
- If the CTO needs to sign off on the requirements and later the completed feature, make sure the CTO is included in the requirements review and the feature acceptance processes
- etc.

Show leadership and eventually, your team will get the message.